# ActiveRecord Causing SQLException in Rspec Test

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

**UPDATE:** My issue is definitely related to [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5885) - it's an issue with ActiveRecord. Still not solved.

I'm trying to get a test to pass in rspec and can't figure out what's going wrong... Here's what I'm getting:

```
Running: spec/models/user_spec.rb
.
.
.
........F

Failures:

  1) User when email address is already taken 
     Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.save
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
     SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": 
     syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.22908 seconds
9 examples, 1 failure
```

Here's the related line in my test:

```
user_with_same_email.save
```

it breaks when trying to write to the db. Development is fine - no issues. 
Thanks

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that @user.dup is getting you. Have you tried instantiating a new user with a duplicate email address, then saving?

Comment: Is it possible that @user was already saved at some point? If so, I think it has an `id` attribute, and I suppose that when you try to save another different record (`user_with_same_email`) with the same id, you are violating a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: From the `Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.save` part, I'm thinking it's a problem saving to the db... I guess I could be wrong though. I haven't tried manually duplicating the record.

Comment: Since I'm not explicitly declaring a user `id` it should just create new ones as I go, right?

Comment: No, if it already has an id, then ActiveRecord will update the existing record when you save. But chances are @user.dup is confusing some ActiveRecord machinery that tracks changes and attempts to only do partial updates (hence the SAVEPOINT).

Comment: If @users has an id, when you dup it, I would the duplicate would retain the id attribute value of the original (could be wrong, I'm not an expert on `dup`. If so you will have problems if you try to save another record with the same id as an existing record, either because you violate a uniqueness constraint, or because the field is a auto-incrementing sequence that doesn't accept manually inserted values.

Comment: Let's try to cross-post with Mark one more time. We're saying the same thing, except I'd say you are doing something the database doesn't like (such as trying to UPDATE a sequence), as opposed to ActiveRecord, since the error is a SQLite Exception.

Comment: And I'm saying that ActiveRecord is generating the SAVEPOINT code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was an old version of sqlite. I installed Homebrew and ran `brew install sqlite3`
A number of errors came up due to files that already existed.  I just renamed them `*.old` and ran `brew link sqlite3`. Problem solved!